# Why can't I change the edits made to my answer?

Tags: support

[An accepted answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/3582/482) that I made to an elementary question here years ago was edited drastically the other day, and when I went to change it back to what I had originally posted, I found I was unable to do so. This is unusual in my experience here, since the tendency is to respect the original poster.

I then flagged the item for administrators, but nothing was done, and since I didn't want my name associated with what I didn't write, I tried to delete the answer, but found that The Rules don't allow authors to delete accepted answers.

So, I am reduced to begging. Please allow me to restore my original post (insufficient as it may be to some, it was enough for the OQ, apparently); or, if The Rules don't allow that, allow me to delete it as it stands. Failing that, I will simply have to retire. I don't need this kind of tsuris.

Comment: I rolled it back. There aren't that many mods here, so it sometimes takes over a day before someone sees the flag. Though the latest edit has my name on it, the contents should be what you wrote + the changes made by the community bot.

Comment: Thank you. I've deleted my comment there, and I'll be happy to delete this question if anyone would like it that way. As it is, I doubt i've caused much disturbance. Useful information about how long to wait for mod attention. A troubling issue for me was my inability to roll back an unsolicited edit on my answer myself; I spose I don't have enough points here in Linguistics.

Comment: I don't think you need to delete this question. I think you have enough points here to qualify for all the general privileges: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges. I guess this was one of those issues that needed mod attention.

Comment: I would've thought so, but I was unable to find a control that would let me roll it back; I've seen them on ELU.SE, but I have ten times more points there.